# Port Forwarding Samba

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, home-networking, samba, raspberry-pi

I am currently running a SAMBA server on my raspberry pi, the problem is that I am only able to access the SMB Server from within my home network. I want to portforward my SMB server so that i can access it from the outside. The problem is that I have no clue on which ports to forward, I have tried other forms but have not managed to get it working. Please try to include images if possible

--

Thank You In Advanced

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SMB uses ports `445/tcp` and/or `139/tcp` (usually just one is enough, but sometimes it's better to forward both). Additionally, the Windows SMB client requires Ping (ICMP Echo) to be open.

Note, however, that many residential ISPs globally block WAN connections from/to these ports, due to the large amount of worms attacking unpatched SMB servers.

Also note that the Windows SMB client *always* uses the same ports. You can't forward 4451/tcp to computer A and 4452/tcp to computer B, because there's no way to specify the port when connecting.

Comment: Forwarding port 445 from a linux server to a nonstandard port with a Mac client worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 2):

for other (i think you have found a solution for yourself lol) : on android you have the appli called "AndSMB" : you have just to forward your NAT port of your server from a high port non standard like 8000 or 9000 to 445, and put your User login and password...thats all...work great!

Enjoy ;)

Oliver